# Kernel density estimator in R with both weighting and boundary corrections?

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, kernel-density

I am attempting to create a kernel density raster in R using weighted point data derived from a raster with fractional cell values (the raster represents the share of the pixel that is covered by agricultural, rather than forest, land, which I then converted into a point dataset to use as a kernel input).

I would also like this data to have boundary corrections applied using a polygon shapefile of the municipality my dataset is drawn from.

I am currently using the *spkernel2d* function from the *"splancs"* package, which computes kernel estimates with a boundary correction, but it does not take weights as an input, meaning that each point, regardless of its value (representative of % agricultural area) is treated the same.

**Are there any kernel packages that can both take weights as an input AND do non-rectangular boundary corrections?**  I have tried the kde.boundary function from package "ks" but it seems to only be suitable for rectangular boundaries.

My current code using the spkernel2d function (no weighting) is as follows:

```
test_agro_pts_300 <- rasterToPoints(rast_agro_300m, fun=NULL, spatial=TRUE) #Converting my input raster to points data

poly <- slot(testmuni, "polygons")[[1]]
poly1 <- slot(poly, "Polygons")[[1]]
coords <- slot(poly1, "coords") #Extracting boundary coordinates from municipality shapefile (polygon)

grd1 <- GridTopology(bbox(rast_agro_300m)[,1] + res(rast_agro_300m)/2, res(rast_agro_300m), dim(rast_agro_300m)[2:1]) #Creating blank output grid for kernel results

b <- coordinates(test_agro_pts_300)
colnames(b)<-c("x","y") #Extracting point coordinates

#Kernels
Sys.time()
k_1500m <- spkernel2d(b, coords, h0=1500, grd1) #Estimating Kernels with 1.5km bandwidth - this function uses quantic kernel function
Sys.time()
df <- data.frame(k_1500m =k_1500m)
kernel1500 <- SpatialGridDataFrame(grd1, data=df)
kernel1500n <- raster(kernel1500) #Converting gridded output kernel estimates to raster
crs(kernel1500n) <- CRS_RC #adding back CRS projection
Sys.time()

plot(kernel1500n) #Visualizing results
```

Comment: I've only ever used the `spatstat` package for kernel density estimation. If you end up looking for another approach, this is a great online resource for that kernel density estimates in that package: http://rspatial.org/rosu/rst/Chapter5.html?highlight=kernel%20density

Comment: @RichPauloo  The Smooth.ppp function worked exactly as needed - thank you!